# How to prove $S : \mathbb{N} \to \{1, 2, 3, ..., i\}$ is countable? Uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I'm trying to grasp countability concepts with regards to set theory and came across this question. I'm trying to prove in some way that certain sets are countable, uncountable, or finite.

If I have two sets, $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{1, 2, 3, ..., i\}$, how can I prove whether the below are countable or uncountable or finite? $A, B, C$ are sets of functions.

$$\begin{align}
A &: \mathbb{N} \to \{1, 2, 3, ..., i\} \\
B &: \{1, 2, 3, ..., i\} \to \mathbb{N} \\
C &: \{1, 2, 3, ..., i\} \to \{1, 2, 3, ..., i\}
\end{align}$$

It can be assumed $i\geq1$ and $|\mathbb{N}| \gt |\{1, 2, 3, ..., i\}|$.

I believe $C$ is finite as it is bijective between two finite sets. What about the other two?

Up to this point I've been using Cantor's Diagonalization and proofs by contradiction. I'm just not so versed in bijection, surjection, injection, etc I think which is relevant for this question.

Comment: What background do you have?  What techniques are available to you to prove that a set is countable?  Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Not quite clear on your question ... what is $A$?  Is that some function?  Seems weird to say that a function is countable or not.  Or is $A$ the set of all possible functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1, 2, 3, ..., i\} $?

Comment: Note that $A$ is at least as large as $\mathscr P (\Bbb N)$.  For any subset $X \subseteq \Bbb N, f(x)= 1$ if $x \in X, f(x)=2$ if $x \notin X$, gives you a distinct function for each subset of $X$.

Comment: @Bram28 the question is worded as "Let A be the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1, 2, 3, ..., i\}$", likewise for B and C.

Comment: @gator Ah .. that's what I figured. But you should add that to your post to make it more clear

Comment: Is the formula $$|\{f|f:A\rightarrow B\}|=|B|^{|A|}$$ usable ? Then you could use transfinite arithmetic.

Comment: For A you should be able to use a standard and straightforward diagonal argument

Comment: @Bram28 my naive thought process is $i^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountably infinite, $\mathbb{N}^i$ is countably infinite, and $i^i$ is countably finite. These are the sizes of the sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $\{1,2,...,i\}$, we will instead work with the set $\{0,1,...,i-1\}$ (at least to analyze $A$). For $A$, note that for any $S\in A$, we have

$$S(\mathbb{N})=(S(1),S(2),...)$$

where $S(n)\in\{0,1,...,i-1\}$. To find the cardinality of $A$, note that there is a bijection between these types of ordered sets and the interval $[0,1]$. Simply note that every real number $x=[0,1]$ can be written as

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{i^k}$$

where $a_i\in\{0,1,...,i-1\}$. For example, if $i=2$, then one such $S$ is

$$S(\mathbb{N})=(S(1),S(2),...)=(1,0,0,1,1,0,...)$$

which corresponds to the number

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{0}{4}+\frac{0}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}+\frac{0}{64}+...$$

We conclude $|A|=|\mathbb{R}|$. We will now go back to $\{1,2,...,i\}$. For $B$, note that any $S\in B$ can be written as

$$S(\{1,2,...,i\})=(S(1),S(2),...,S(i))$$

where $S(n)\in \mathbb{N}$. To find the cardinality of this set, note that there is a bijection between $B$ and natural numbers whose prime factorization includes the first $i$ primes. This bijection can be written as

$$S(\{1,2,...,i\})=(S(1),S(2),...,S(i))\leftrightarrow 2^{S(1)}3^{S(2)}...p_i^{S(i)}$$

Since this set is countable, we conclude $|B|=|\mathbb{N}|$. Finally, for $C$ it is easy to see that there are $i^i$ different functions from $\{1,2,...,i\}$ onto itself. For every element in the set you pick, there are $i$ choices for it to map to. We conclude $|C|=i^i$.